# How do I get the number of requests per second from Apache log between 2 dates/time?

Tags: linux, apache, monitoring, network-monitoring

What command can I use to analyse Apache's log file that tells me between 11am of day x and 13pm of day x the average request per second was..? The os is linux (red hat)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get "requests per second" for Apache in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345546/how-to-get-requests-per-second-for-apache-in-linux)

Comment: it's not a duplicate. She is asking for historical logs, not realtime.

Comment: Please, can you specify if you are asking the mean or peak reqs/s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> between 11am of day x and 13pm

My clock doesn't go all the way to 13pm. How are things on Airstrip 1?

Assuming you meant 1pm....

Something like...

```
awk 'BEGIN {started=0}
   /\[29\/Oct\/2010:11/ {
          started=1}
   /\[29\/Oct\/2010:1[3-9]/ {
          print count/(2*60*60);
          exit; }
   // { 
          if (started) count++;
      }' <access_log
```

Comment: your (smart btw) script measures the average, but not the peak req/s

Comment: You didn't ask for that - but it's trivial to add.