# requests per second from Apache log files?

Tags: apache, performance-testing, throughput

Is it possible to determine a metric for requests per second from Apache log files? If so, how does one go about this?

cheers,
Cathal.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Can you specify if you mean realtime or historical logs?

Comment: Also, do you mean average or peak reqs/s ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to parse out entries in your [Access Log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#accesslog) to view requests per second.

The Common Log Format looks something like this:

> 127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326

You could use Java or some other sort of strong text parsing language to find "GET" entries in the Access Log and then "sum up" the number of requests per second by grouping the date/time portions (**"10/Oct/2000:13:55:36"**).  Those "GET" entries that match in their date/time portion would be included in the requests per second portion.

From there, you could gather further metrics about particular times of the day, maximum requests per second, etc...

**Edit**
Looks like this has already been asked as well on SOF: [How to get “requests per second” for Apache in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345546/how-to-get-requests-per-second-for-apache-in-linux)

Comment: The answer you refer in SOF it's specific  for realtime, but it will be interesting to have answers regarding historial logs.